# How can you create a button that interactively changes the location on the map, asking the user for the new coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

**Javascript**

```
function newCoordinate (){

}
```

**Html 5**

```
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <input type="button" id="recenter" value="re-center" onclick="moveToLocation(50.63,0);"/>
        <input type="button" id="MoveToRandom" value="random" onclick="moveToRandom();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please, imagine you know nothing about your own issue (yes, imagine us) now, read again your question. Do you understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/DuRhR/ that allows you center the map to the input latitude and longitude coordinates. Another button pans the map to a random point.

You can also look at this  tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

Javascript functions:

```
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4375, 12.3358);
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

function moveToLocation() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value,
    document.getElementById("lng").value);
    map.panTo(center);
    marker.setPosition(center);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function moveToRandom() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(getRandom(-90, 90), getRandom(-180, 180));
    map.panTo(center);
    marker.setPosition(center);
}

initialize();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<input type="text" id="lat" /> 
<input type="text" id="lng" />

<input type="button" id="recenter" value="re-center" onclick="moveToLocation();" />
<input type="button" id="MoveToRandom()" value="random" onclick="moveToRandom();" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much user2314737.